# Find Euclidean distance based on cell size

Tags: distance, euclidean

Usually, Euclidean distance is defined as `squareroot((x1 - x2)^2 - (y1-y2)^2)` but, instead of having `x` and `y` values you have a cell size of `20`.

How can to calculate the Euclidean distance between the yellow boxes?

[image]

Further context:

[image]

Comment: Do you know the relative position of the cells i.e. (0,0 and 4,1)?

Comment: Nope sorry,  just the cell size.

Comment: Are the cells always in the same relative position?
Otherwise it seems like the task is to calculate the distance between two unknown locations, which seems tricky.

Comment: I have another image for further reference.

Comment: In this specific case, given cell size 20 and measuring distance to/from the centre of the cells: 
x=20 y=60 so D= 63.245. 
This is a specific answer, to solve for other cases we need to know the relative position of the cells. a formula in that case would be:
d = √((cellsize(cell2y-cell1y))²+(cellsize(cell2x-cell1x))²)
i.e. d = √(4000 ) = 63.245

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it as an answer, thank you.

Comment: Jusr because cell size is fixed doesn't mean that there is no Y component. It just means that X and Y are multiples of some constant *w*. This is more pure math than a GIS problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, given cell size 20 and measuring distance to/from the centre of the cells:

```
x=20 y=60. Therefore: d=63.245
```

This is a specific answer, to solve for **other cases** we need to know the relative position of the cells.
A formula in that case would be:

```
d = √( ( cellsize(cell2y-cell1y) )²+( cellsize(cell2x-cell1x) )² ) 

i.e. d = √(4000) = 63.245
```